# SQL Server Stored Procedure - INSERT command - DateTime error sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Procedure is sync, ok? But, how explain that.

I have a table with the fields (not specific like that):

```
ID    INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
DATE  DATETIME NOT NULL
```

The insert executed by SP is: (This SP is call inside another one)

```
INSERT TABLE  VALUES ( SYSDATETIME()  )
```

BUT, the table values  are:

```
ID | DATETIME  
6  | 2017-08-23 09:40:00.000
7  | 2017-08-23 09:39:46.690
```

How is it possible? 
The ID 6 is "the most up-to-date", not ID 7.

In our context we need to order by IDENTITY field.
I cannot order the query by DateTime, because the others fields. E.g.:

```
ID | DATETIME                 | ACTION
6  | 2017-08-23 09:40:00.000  | Production Start
7  | 2017-08-23 09:39:46.690  | Production End
```

I executed the End action before the Start action. The timeline is wrong.

Comment: getdate() is used to get the time upto milliseconds where as SysDateTime used to get time up to Nanoseconds

Comment: @Srini131 The difference is between minutes first, SysDateTime and nanoseconds should not create any problem.

Comment: @Srini131 I think the user is asking why ID 6 has a time greater than ID 7, aside from the precision

Comment: @Claudio (Asker) Was by any chance server clock was reset during this time? Did you notice this only once or this is happening often.

Comment: This is not possible IMO. Did you accidently update the previous record, is there any other logic in the second sp?

Comment: Sorry @Srini131,  The correct issue is  why ID 6 has a time greater than ID 7 , aside from the precision.   Thanks Jacob H

Comment: @mr_eclair .   No chance .  It does not occur every executed, it's one every one million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error encountered !

The SQL Function SYSDATETIME "Returns a datetime2(7) value that contains the date and time of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql

On our server we found (at EventViewer logs) two routines that are synchronizing the server clock, conflicting each other.

PreviousTime 2017-08-31T12:03:03.947848200Z
NewTime 2017-08-31T12:02:06.821000000Z
ProcessId 0x854
ProcessName DSHO_SincPCnetV11.exe

PreviousTime 2017-08-31T12:21:02.471426500Z
NewTime 2017-08-31T12:21:59.544982100Z
ProcessId 0x484
ProcessName C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your process had some concurrency hell.

That is the explanation from the MSDN. (better than my previous it)

> Consecutive values within a transaction – A transaction inserting
>   multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows
>   because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values
>   must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock
>   on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property

Comment: I think you have correctly identified the issue but your explanation is quite confusing.

Comment: I agree with you Sean, I edit it, and I copied the explanation from MSDN.

Comment: Thanks @MaurícioPontaltiNeri

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri  I changed my first SP including variable datetime ..     DECLARE "@@CurrentDate" = SYSDATETIME ()  and pass to second one. The new insert is    INSERT TABLE VALUES @@CurrentDate  ,  but the result was the same.  Is there another way to resolve that ?

Comment: @Maurício Pontalti Neri, but his code INSERTs 1 only row, where are "Consecutive values within a transaction"?

Comment: @sepupic he'd put only an example to us image out the problem. An code fragment

Comment: @ClaudioParra, I figured it is a limitation of SQL Server. In your business context, what is so important the identity be sequential?

Comment: @ClaudioParra, please precise if your procedure makes only 1 insert or there are many rows inserted. The code you posted has no transaction at all and the single insert ... values...(1 value) is in autocommit mode meaning 1 insert = 1 row =1 transaction

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri,  Inserts 1 only row for each request, but has multiple request at same time. Also, we do not use BEGIN TRANSACTION inside the SP, it could be a problem ?

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri In our context we need use Identity field to know the sequence of operations,  if we change to Date Field the others values are incompatible, Example:    ID 1  DATETIME  2017-08-23 09:40:00.000 ACTION  Start ,  ID 2  DATETIME  2017-08-23 09:39:46.690  ACTION End

Comment: >>>Inserts 1 only row for each request, but has multiple request at same time. Also, we do not use BEGIN TRANSACTION inside the SP, it could be a problem ?<<< This is not a problem, it only means that "Consecutive values within a transaction " is not your case. You have 1 transaction for 1 insert that inserts exactly 1 value

Comment: >>>In our context we need use Identity field to know the sequence of operations<<< Why cannot you use datetime2 to keep your sequence ordered?

Comment: @sepupic  Exactly.  But how explain that ?!  Indexes ? Plan Cache ?

Comment: @ClaudioParra if you are using SQL 2012 you can try to change your Identity to a sequence https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql. Maybe it makes more sense in your business context.

Comment: @Claudio Parra, I think your procedure is not the only thing that accesses that table

Comment: @ClaudioParra, The case described by Maurício Pontalti Neri also can take place, not in your procedure but there can be someone else who does uses multiple inserts in 1 transaction

Comment: @sepupic I updated my question to better exemplify why we cannot use the datetime field to order the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not reproducible.  You are doing something other than what you describe.

I ran the following test:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TTest (
 [ID] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, [DT] datetime NOT NULL
);


--run the following two steps manually multiple times
INSERT INTO dbo.TTest
VALUES (SYSDATETIME());

SELECT * FROM dbo.TTest;
--

DROP TABLE dbo.TTest
```

The result was:

```
ID  DT
1   2017-08-23 09:05:23.450
2   2017-08-23 09:05:36.397
3   2017-08-23 09:05:57.313
```